# Are dynos separate applications or computing horsepower?

Tags: heroku, server

So I was reading this book, *Heroku Up and Running*, and it essentially showed a diagram and said that an application will have, let's say, 8 dynos, and each one runs separate applications, which completely confused me. So, my question is this: If I have one app, and 10 or 12 dynos, does that mean I'm gonna have one powerful application to handle a bunch of requests, or am I gonna have 12 dynos I need to configure seperatly? I'm pretty new to all this server hosting, so if you could keep the jargon low, that would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each dyno can be seen as a separate server, each of them runs the same version of the application.
So if you have 12 dynos, you have 12 servers, with heroku's router sending each request to one or another.

Comment: Would each have the same database to connect to?

Comment: Yes, of course. When you provision an Heroku addon (such as postgresql), a config var is set on your app (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) holding the database credentials.

Comment: I see. Thanks for helping me, you are super helpful!